# Highlight text for search keyword based on complete keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to highlight the keyword used for search in the blog. So far i managed to used the following script http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight/demo_en.html

but this script doesn't match the exact keywords if one wishes to. It is working as it has been programmed to.

When one select option `exact: "exact",` in the function it match's and highlights each word `Per id` of search keyword.

How can i modify this script so that it match whole keywords not part of keywords .

In this fiddle example it should only highlight `Per id` rather than occurrences of `Per` or `id`..

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/gq4hkvgd/

```
    var val2 = "Per id";
            var options = {
                exact: "exact",
                style_name_suffix:false,
                keys:val2
            }
            $('.wrapper').SearchHighlight(options);
```

Comment: Look at the answers, or website of [Tim Down](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down). He has scripts that do this:

Comment: I think the keys value is programmed to split the values on white space. You need to alter the plugin to make this work.

Comment: I event played with key value but it give me same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var q = options.keys != undefined ? options.keys.toLowerCase().split(/[\s\+\.]+/) : SearchHighlight.decodeURL(ref, SearchHighlight.engines);
```

To this:

```
var q = options.keys != undefined ? options.keys.toLowerCase().split(/[\+\.]+/) : SearchHighlight.decodeURL(ref, SearchHighlight.engines);
```

Now the function doesn't split keywords on white spaces anymore and you will get the desired result.

http://jsfiddle.net/gq4hkvgd/4/